# WSO2 - Extend Allowed URI Length to Maximum

Tags: url, request, wso2, uri

We have an API published on WSO2. It works perfectly.

When I send my request like the picture below, it responses 200 as I wanted:
[image]

I just wanted to test my request by adding more `deleted=false` query. So, I can send request until the request's size is 5.75 KB. I see stil 200 OK nicely. You can see on picture below:
[image]

But, if I reach request size 5.76KB by adding 1 more `deleted=false` query, I see this error:
[image]

As I searched on internet, I see that `the REST API supports Uniform Resource Locators (URLs) with a length of up to 6000 characters.`

My question is, how can I extend this limit? Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the shared screenshot, it seems the Backend itself is responding back with a 400 Bad Request status code. The API Manager doesn't have any restrictions on large query parameters in the URI. So, this error is coming up from your actual Backend service, which is not able to handle a large request.

To confirm this behavior, you can enable the WIRE logs in the API Manager server and troubleshoot the behavior. If the request is dispatched to the Backend and the Backend is responded with 400 Bad Request means, the Backend is only capable of handling requests up to 5.75 KB in your case.

Also, as an alternate check, you can also try invoking the actual Backend service URL from the Postman (direct invocation and not via WSO2) and verify the behavior with large requests.

Given below are few documentations related to enabling WIRE logs and understanding the WIRE logs

- [WSO2 API Manager v3.1.0: Enable WIRE Logs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/#enable-gateway-wire-logs)
- [WSO2 API Manager v2.6.0: Enable WIRE Logs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Setting+Up+Logging)
- [How to read and understand WIRE Logs](https://medium.com/api-integration-essentials/how-to-read-and-understand-wire-logs-in-wso2-products-c384af0b8ea5)

Comment: I tried the alternative way, and it accepts 6.63 KB as an example. Are you exactly sure WSO2 APIM doesn't have any restriction ?

Comment: Did you face any error traces in the carbon logs? If so please share it. Also, please mention the APIM version you are using.

Comment: @Wicaledon, in addition to what Saranki requested, you can enable the WIRE logs and verify whether the Backend is responding with the 400 or not. I've tested the scenario in APIM 3.2.0, and am able to invoke it till the Backend (JSONPlaceHolder) throws a 400 status (which is more than 7KB).

Comment: As you guys said, that problem comes from my backend. I added `server.max-http-header-size: 10KB` line to application.yaml file. I can send request more than 5.75 KB. But I want to share some details. I can send request until 7.75 KB. I checked that WSO2 is adding some new headers like 2.5KB while gateway is sending the request to service endpoint

Comment: Great!!. The API Manager will add few headers like `User-Agent`, `Connection`, etc, and `X-JWT-Assertion` (if the Backend JWT is enabled) while sending the request to the Backend. You may want to increase a little more in the Backend servers to accept the expected limit as per your requirement.

Comment: @Athiththan  one question, can you investigate what is the use of this x-jwt-assertion and can we disable unused headers in WSO2?

Comment: The `X-JWT-Assertion` is used to pass the user details to the backend server. You can learn more about in [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/). If you don't want that, you can simply disable that from the configurations. Further, other headers are part of the API Manager process (most HTTP connection-related). So they will be sent out anyhow.

Comment: @Athiththan thanks for answer. I have 1 more question, I added a comparison table in https://prnt.sc/1jew561 . from postman I send `Bearer <my jwt token>` in `authorization` header. and gateway sends same token to service too. why it adds another token in `x-jwt-assertion` header automatically?

Comment: @Athiththan and 1 more question :) you said I can disable it from the configurations, how can I on Publisher ? or should I add a new script ?

Comment: Those are two different tokens. It is not recommended to pass the Authorization Access Token to the Backend unless you have a special requirement. So, when you want to pass few information about the end-user and the API, you can use the `X-JWT-Assertion` token to send those details to the Backend. This is a different token which gets built during the runtime of the API invocation. Further, if you don't want the `X-JWT`, you can simply disable that and keep on passing the actual Access token to the Backend. Also note that the `X-Forwarded` and `X-Amazon` are populated from the LB and not APIM.

Comment: You have to disable the `X-JWT-Assertion` from the `TOML` configuration. There aren't any UI configurations available to disable that. So you have to open the `deployment.toml` and under `[apim.jwt]` make the `enable` false.